# Get inventory list from PayPal Buy Now Button

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I would like to integrate a PayPal Button into my website which has an inventory configured via PayPal. So far so good. But as soon as every item has been sold the button should switch to an "SOLD OUT" info. Is it possible to get the inventory amount via the PayPal API? And if yes....how?

Any ideas or experiences?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier if you control this in your application. You'd have more control in things.

Comment: in which application? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: I think Hadagaberto means to say that would be easier for you to program everything yourself, but that doesn't really seem to apply to you as you're asking specifically about PayPal buttons

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can track your inventory with PayPal button. Check the link below for the steps.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/step_2/